# Is there a replacement for setHandler in Elasticsearch SDK 8?

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I noticed that the docs show setHandler has been removed from the php es sdk in 8.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/8.11/breaking_changes.html

Is there a replacement for it? How would I include the aws signature for an opensearch server?

Comment: I wonder if you can configure this with the HTTP client now? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/8.11/http-client.html